# Что делает этот dll?

Tags: dll

хотел бы узнать,что делает этот dll,после того как узнал,что на dll можно писать вирусы  у меня появилась паранойя. Сам бы проверял,но не знаю как.

https://yadi.sk/d/EJStrCIbeNnnOw

Comment: «на dll можно писать вирусы» — хотите я вам одну страшную вещь скажу? На **любом исполняемом файле** можно писать вирусы. Даже на exe и на bat. Если повозиться с макросами, то даже на doc.

Comment: @andreymal неее)) макросы - чепуха(подтверждение просит),я знаю способ лучше(уязвимость)

Comment: Ну тогда сообщу, что попадались уязвимости в картинках png)

Answer (score 2):

Для таких случаев есть: https://www.virustotal.com и https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/

Анализ файла:
[VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/688504053bc64e462644dc5e6929324a99d5f4f68127b6efd7eb7b4f7017e042/details) и
[HybrydAnalyz](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/688504053bc64e462644dc5e6929324a99d5f4f68127b6efd7eb7b4f7017e042)